# WPF: Change Progress-Bar color according its value and View Model property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Ok so i have this property in my `View Model`:

```
public bool IsChecked
{
    get { return _isChecked; }
    set
    {
        _isChecked = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // I also try OnPropertyChanged("IsChecked");
    }
}
```

And as you can see this implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

When this `property` is changing i can see the it notify and get the correct value.

This is my `Progress-Bar`:

```
<ProgressBar Name="progressBarColumn"
             Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
             Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
             Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
```

And my `Progress-Bar style`:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar" >
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Border Name="PART_Track" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBackgroundColor}"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBackgroundColor}"
                            BorderThickness="1" />
                    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillColor}" 
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillColor}" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                    <DataTrigger Value="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                        <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="LayoutTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"/>
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So this is the things that  currently not working:

1. When my `Progress-Bar` reach the `value` of `100%` i want its `Background` color will change so i add this `DataTrigger`:

   ```
   <DataTrigger Value="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
       <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
   </DataTrigger>
   ```

So this not effect at all over my `Pregress-Bar` color when its reach `100%`.

I even also try:

```
<DataTrigger Value="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

2. When my `View Model` `IsChecked` `property` is set to `false` i want that my `Progress-Bar` `Background` color will change to `Red` - also this is not working.

I try to search many solutions but again and again same results - my ``` Progress-Bar``color ``` not changing at all.

EDIT:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar2" TargetType="ProgressBar">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Value="100" Property="Value">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ProgressBarFillCompleteColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
        </Trigger>

        <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar" >
                <Grid x:Name="Root">
                    <Border Name="PART_Track" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}"
                            BorderBrush="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}"
                            BorderThickness="1" />
                    <Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding  Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding  Background}" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Do you want to change the color of the bar, or the color of the container which contains the bar?

Comment: I want to be able control they both is this is possible

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private int _Progress;
private int _Progress;
public int Progress
{
    get {
        return _Progress;

    }
    set
    {
        _Progress = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
    }
}
```

Then change your style. It will be better to use Style.Triggers instead

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Value="100" Property="Value">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Pink"/>
    </Trigger>

    <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

And modify background binding on your barders inside template

```
<Border Name="PART_Track" 
    CornerRadius="0" 
    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
    BorderThickness="1" />
<Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
    CornerRadius="0" 
    Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
    BorderThickness="1" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

It will be enough to change Background when progress will be 100, but when progress will be more than 100 ( if you need it) foreground and background will be switched to default value. If you need to change color for progress >= 100 then you need ValueConverter instead of triggers.

EDIT:

Full solution.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.ProgressWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication3"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="ProgressWindow" Height="200" Width="400">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBarFillCompleteColor" Color="Green"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ProgressBorderBrushColor" Color="Gray"/>

        <Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="AliceBlue"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource ProgressBorderBrushColor}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar" >
                        <Grid x:Name="Root">
                            <Border Name="PART_Track" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderThickness="1" />
                            <Border Name="PART_Indicator" 
                            CornerRadius="0" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                            BorderThickness="1" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                                <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="LayoutTransform">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                                <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Width" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Height}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Root" Property="Height" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Width}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="False" Binding="{Binding IsChecked}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <Trigger Value="100" Property="Value">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <DockPanel>
        <ProgressBar Name="progressBarColumn" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="20" Minimum="0" Maximum="100"
                        Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                        Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
        <StackPanel>
            <Button Content="Start" Click="Button_Click"/>
            <CheckBox Content="Check me" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

View and viewmodel

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WpfApplication3
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ProgressWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ProgressWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public ProgressWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
        }

        private int _Progress;
        public int Progress
        {
            get
            {
                return _Progress;

            }
            set
            {
                _Progress = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Progress"));
            }
        }

        private bool _IsChecked;
        public bool IsChecked
        {
            get
            {
                return _IsChecked;

            }
            set
            {
                _IsChecked = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"));
            }
        }

        private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Progress = 0;
            await Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                var value = 0;
                while (value < 100)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(500);
                    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                        new Action(() =>
                        {
                            Progress += 10;
                        }));
                }
            }); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When i change Green color to my color --> {DynamicResource ProgressBarFillColor} this is not working and when the valuie is 100 this volor not changing

Comment: OK so please see my edit according you suggestion, i have now two problems: 1. when the Progress-Bar  value is less 100 i want the Background color will be Gray, currently this white, the complete color is fine. 2. IsChecked trigger not working and not change the color to Red